# Number of solutions to a Grobner base and irreducible monomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, groebner-basis

I want to find the number of solutions to a Grobner basis.

For example:
$G = \{x^2-1, y^2 -1 , (x-1)(y-1)\}$.

In the textbook, it says there are three irreducible monomials $\{ 1, x,y\}$ and hence three solutions.

I don't understand how to get these irreducible monomials from $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an ideal $I$, $\Delta_<(I)$,the footprint of $I$ is defined to be the set of monomials $X$ such that $X$ is not a leading monomial of any polynomial in $I$ ($<$ denotes the fixed monomial ordering). Here, $G$ is a Groebner Basis thus it is enough to check the monomials which is not divisible by $x^2,y^2$ or $xy$ which is the set $\Delta_<(I)=\{1,x,y\}$. If the footprint of an ideal is finite then the number of elements in the footprint is equal to the number of points in the zero locus, counted with multiplicity.

Comment: Could you explain what "counted with multiplicity" means? If the leading monomials is x^3. will both x and x^2 be irreducible? I think x^5 is also indivisible by x^3.

Comment: Well, for example if you take $I=(x^2)\subseteq \mathbb{C}[x]$, the footprint of $I, \Delta_<(I)=\{1,x\}$. But as you see there is only one solution, namely $0$, which has multiplicity $2$.

Comment: I understand multiplicity now, but why $x^3$ not in the footprint of $I$.

Comment: $x^3$ is divisible by $x^2$, which is a leading monomial in one of the polynomials of $G$. You ned to use the definition of Groebner bases at some point!